# the code below demonstrates how to group shapes thru GroupShapes and name them, but I need to expand this to GroupS of ShapeS

Tags: excel, vba

In the code below demonstrates how to group a number shapes thru groupShapes, but what I need to accomplish is not just 1 group of shapes but I need MANY groupS of shapes. Is this possible with the current EXCEL object model?

if you can point me in right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

''''

```
   Sub CreateSymbol()
        Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
        Set thisSheet = Sheets("Symbol Editor")

        Dim allShapes As Shapes
        Set allShapes = thisSheet.Shapes

       allShapes.SelectAll
       If TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then
       Dim theGroup As Object
       Set theGroup = Selection.Group

       theGroup.name = "MyBigGroup"
    
       Dim grpShapes As GroupShapes
       Set grpShapes = theGroup.ShapeRange.GroupItems
       MsgBox allShapes.Count
       Debug.Print "shapes in this group = " & grpShapes.Count
     End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "many groups of shapes"? You will have to specify exactly how you want to group it, and what you want in the groups, but making several groups shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: the software will take DrawingObjects and group them to create  "Symbols" such as a motor, pump or a control valve.  A "Display" -A worksheet-  Will contain several symbols.

Comment: I am afraid your answer does not clarify anything against the above clarification question... The code must be able to **somehow, identify the shapes to be part of a group**. "Create symbols" is abstract, it should be only your concern, but it has nothing to do with the needed clarification... What **common characteristic/property do the shapes to be part of a group have**? Do they have a similar name (the same prefix followed by something different)? The same colors, used fonts etc.... And based on what to specifically name these specific groups.